# A version of Vectorize() for apply() rather than mapply()?

Tags: r, vectorization

Is there a version of `Vectorize` that uses `apply` rather than `mapply`?
I would like to vectorize a function that takes vector input in a way that allows me 
to pass an array to that function and have a vector returned.

Of course I can write my own wrapper and that works well enough.  But I wondered if this functionality is built in?

I can also use `Vectorize`, but then I have to convert the matrix input to a data.frame for it work.  For example:

```
LAMBDA <- cbind(c(1, .5, .5), c(.5, 1, .5), c(.5, .5, 1))
THETA <- c(0,0,1)
NU <- 21
my.data <- array(1:6, c(3,2))
my.fun <- Vectorize(pmt, vectorize.args="x")
```

Then

```
> my.fun(my.data, mean=THETA, S=LAMBDA, df=NU)
[1] 0.4404142 0.8130572 0.9667065 0.9961166 0.9996274 0.9999676
```

Which is not what I want, but

```
> my.data <- data.frame(my.data)
> my.fun(my.data, mean=THETA, S=LAMBDA, df=NU)
       X1        X2 
0.8130572 0.9996274
```

is what I want.

BTW, `pmt` is from the mnormt package and is a multivariate student's t cdf.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to define a function `my.fun` to which you pass in a matrix `my.data`, and the `my.fun` will just "know" that it needs to apply the function to each column of `my.data`. This is what the `apply()` function is meant to do; you don't need the `Vectorize` call. So why not just do this:

```
my.data <- array(1:6, c(3,2))

> apply(my.data, 2, pmt, mean=THETA, S=LAMBDA, df=NU)

[1] 0.8130572 0.9996274
```

Comment: Do you mean `my.data` can be a vector instead of a matrix?  If so, can you just make it a one column matrix?

Comment: If so, all you need is `apply(matrix(my.data, nrow=3), 2, pmt, mean=THETA, S=LAMBDA, df=NU)`.  That works on both vectors and matrices.

Comment: @Aaron's solution is better than my if then else solution, at least in terms of readability.  I guess `Vectorize` does do something similar in `args <- lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1L], eval, parent.frame())`.  Not that I fully understand it.